# Pass the Longitude/Latitude dynamically as Waypoint using HERE MAP API

Tags: javascript

How can I pass `waypoint0`, `waypoint1` as dynamic?
When I tried with the below options it's not taking the proper value of `lat` and `lng`.

`waypoint0: geo!lat,lng` and `waypoint0: geo!latlng{lat,lng}`,

I am getting values from :

```
var lat = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Latitude; 
var lng = location.Location.DisplayPosition.Longitude;
```

Just wanted to set the `lat` and `lng` in `waypoint` as dynamic values. Could anyone please suggest me the solution.

Thanks,
Sneha